# Rearrange a text into a different order using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a text `RAW/+A/@B/abs.m>C` and it has to be converted to `A.B.C`

Could someone help me with an efficient SQL. I am struggling to build one.

This is the rule to be followed - use whatever is to the right of '>' preceded by whatever comes after each '+' or '@'

e.g. `fixedpoint/fixedpoint/+embedded/@fi/abs.m>abs` 
 becomes   `embedded.fi.abs`

Comment: You say you are "struggling to build one".. can you post your attempt and what error you got so we can help you?

Comment: @Dilip Question's title is misleading, there is nothing about order(it looks like `REGEXP` that get parts between `+@>` up to `/` and concatenate with `.`

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one instance of each special character `+ @ >` then the below will work.

```
declare @table table (c1 varchar(64))
insert into @table
values
('RAW/+A/@B/abs.m>C '),
('fixedpoint/fixedpoint/+embedded/@fi/abs.m>abs')

;with cte as(
select
    fst = substring(c1,charindex('+',c1) + 1,charindex('/',substring(c1,charindex('+',c1) + 1,8000)) - 1)
    ,mid = substring(c1,charindex('@',c1) + 1,charindex('/',substring(c1,charindex('@',c1) + 1,8000)) - 1)
    ,lst = substring(c1,charindex('>',c1) + 1,8000)
from
    @table)

select
    fst + '.' + mid + '.' + lst
from cte
```

Comment: Well this is very simplified scenario. I would expect recursive CTE :)

Comment: True @LukaszSzozda and at that point i'd just use a tally table, split them, and pivot.

Comment: Yes, tally table is also possible approach

Answer (score 0):

Although I am sure you have other variations, this would suffice for your example:

```
;WITH CTE (Column1) AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        VALUES
            ('RAW/+A/@B/abs.m>C')
    ) AS A (Column1)
)

SELECT SUBSTRING(Column1, CHARINDEX('+', Column1) + 1, 1) + '.' +
SUBSTRING(Column1, CHARINDEX('@', Column1) + 1, 1) + '.' +
SUBSTRING(Column1, CHARINDEX('>', Column1) + 1, 1) AS Result
FROM CTE
```

It would assume there are only one of each of the special characters as well as only one of each of the "to find" characters.

Answer (score 0):

Just PoC that uses recursive CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT  id
         ,orig   = c
         ,result = CAST('' AS VARCHAR(MAX))
         ,i      = PATINDEX('%[+@>]%', c)
         ,s      = c
  FROM tab
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c.id,
         c.orig,
         c.result+'.'+CAST(LEFT(sub.z,IIF(PATINDEX('%[/]%',sub.z)-1 < 0, LEN(c.s),
                    PATINDEX('%[/]%',sub.z)-1)) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
         PATINDEX('%[+@>]%', sub.z),
         sub.z
  FROM cte c
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES (SUBSTRING(c.s, i+1, LEN(c.s)))) AS sub(z)
  WHERE PATINDEX('%[+@>]%', c.s) <> 0
)
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES orig, STUFF(result,1,1,'') AS f
FROM cte
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY LEN(result) DESC);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b51cd76e922ba1646296ade60b54d237)**

Output:

```
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│                     orig                      │          f          │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ RAW/+A/@B/abs.m>C                             │ A.B.C               │
│ fixedpoint/fixedpoint/+embedded/@fi/abs.m>abs │ embedded.fi.abs     │
│ fasfasfds/@ABC/asdsa/+eqwe/@afdsda/asdsa>XYZ  │ ABC.eqwe.afdsda.XYZ │
│ some_text                                     │ null                │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```